# Bitflip and negate

Tags: code-golf, string, math, bitwise

Given an integer, make an expression that produces it from `0` using unary negation `-` and bitwise complement `~` (`~n` = `-n-1`), with the operators applied right to left.

```
...
-3  = ~-~-~0
-2  = ~-~0
-1  = ~0
 0  = 0
 1  = -~0
 2  = -~-~0
 3  = -~-~-~0
...
```

Your expression must be as short as possible, which means no redundant parts of `~~`, `--`, `-0`, or `00`. Output or print the expression as a string or a sequence of characters.

```js
var QUESTION_ID=92598,OVERRIDE_USER=20260;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/92598/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: So... you want us to [put our thing down, flip it and reverse it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UODX_pYpVxk)?

Comment: whitespace between ~ and 0 allowed?

Comment: No, output the strings exactly.

Comment: Obligatory https://xkcd.com/153/

Answer (score 17):

## Python, 32 bytes

```python
lambda x:("-~"*abs(x))[x<0:]+"0"
```

Anonymous lambda function. Given an integer x writes "-~" abs(x) times and  removes the first char if x is negative, then a zero is added to the end.

Comment: Aw, beat me to it.

Comment: I just wrote the same too - with `n` in the place of `x` and `'` in the place of `"` :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Then you can safely consider it a dupe.

Answer (score 16):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>33</s> 31 bytes

```
f=x=>x<0?"~"+f(~x):x&&"-"+f(-x)
```

Recursion < built-ins < loops (at least in this case). Basically unevaluates the input:

- if it's less than 0, flip it and add a `~` to the string;
- if it's more than 0, negate it and add a `-` to the string;
- if it's exactly 0, return 0.

Takes advantage of this pattern:

```
 0         = 0
-1 = ~( 0) = ~0
+1 = -(-1) = -~0
-2 = ~(+1) = ~-~0
+2 = -(-2) = -~-~0
-3 = ~(+2) = ~-~-~0
+3 = -(-3) = -~-~-~0
etc.
```

Answer (score 11):

## Pyth, <s>14</s> <s>13</s> 12 Bytes

```
_<>0Q+0sm"~-
```

*-2 Bytes thanks to @StevenH.*

**[test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=_%3C%3E0Q%2B0sm%22%7E-&input=4&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=-4%0A-3%0A-2%0A-1%0A0%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A4&debug=0)**

Decided to try out Pyth, so i translated [my python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/92598/bitflip-and-negate/92606#92606) to it. Any help welcome!

#### Explanation:

```
_<>0Q+0sm"~-     
        m"~-     # Map "~-" onto the input (= a list of n times "~-").
       s         # Join the list to a string.
     +0          # Add "0" in front. 
 <>0Q            # Slice off the last char if the input is negative.
_                # Reverse the whole thing.
```

Comment: Use implicit input at the end to save one byte: `>0` instead of `<Q0`

Comment: @StevenH. Thank you! Now we're in a tie with the shortest answer!

Comment: Very different solution (that, unfortunately, doesn't save any bytes): `tW>0Q_+0sm"~-`

Comment: @StevenH.   Golfed your solution down to 12: `_<>0Q+0sm"~-` I hope your okay with me adding this to my solution.

Answer (score 8):

## C, 46 bytes

```
m(x){putchar(x?x<0?126:45:48);x&&m(-x-(x<0));}
```

Unlike most (all?) other answers, this one outputs the operators `~` and `-` one by one.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
Ä„-~×¹0‹i¦}0J
```

**Explanation**

```
 „-~           # the string "-~"
Ä   ×          # repeated abs(input) times
     ¹0‹i¦}    # if input is negative, remove the first char
           0J  # join with 0
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=w4TigJ4tfsOXwrkw4oC5acKmfTBK&input=LTM)

Answer (score 7):

## Retina, <s>19</s> 17 bytes

Replace the number with unary, with a zero on the end. Replace each `1` with `-~`. Remove double negative if there is one.

```
\d+
$*10
1
-~
--
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XGQrCiQqMTAKMQotfgotLQo&input=LTM)

[**All test cases at once**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYApcZCsKJCoxMAoxCi1-Ci0tCg&input=LTMKLTIKLTEKMAoxCjIKMw) (slightly modified program to support multiple test cases)

Comment: 17: http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYApcZCsKJCoxMAoxCi1-Ci0tCg&input=LTMKLTIKLTEKMAoxCjIKMw

Answer (score 7):

## Perl <strike>38 35 33</strike> (23 + 1 for -p) 24

```
s/\d+/"-~"x$&.0/e;s;--;
```

-13 thanks to Dada

Comment: You probably meant `-p` instead of `-r`.  Also you can get rid of those last parenthesis and semicolon : `if$h<0` is enough.

Comment: I did, thanks. I've been writing too many answers in sed I guess.

Comment: Probably, yea. (Get rid of the last 2 parenthesis too)

Comment: You can also save 2 bytes by doing `$h<0&&s;.;` instead of `s/.// if $h<0`. (`-p` adds a `;` at the end of the code, so no need for the last `;` of `s;.;;`. And `a if b` is roughly equivalent to `b && a`, but in this case it saves you one byte because you can remove the space)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know -p added a `;` too.

Comment: A 25 bytes version : `perl -l60pe 's/\d+/"-~"x$&/e;s;--;'`

Comment: @Dada got it down to 24 by appending a 0 in the substitution instead of using -l60

Comment: Very neat. Have a `+1`

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, 41 bytes

<s>`f n=['-'|n>0]++(tail$[1..abs n]>>"-~")++"0"`</s>

```
f n|n<0=tail$f(-n)|x<-[1..n]>>"-~"=x++"0"
```

Thanks to nimi for 3 bytes

Comment: `tail` fails for `n=0`. You can use `drop 1` instead.

Comment: @nimi Thanks; I have no idea how I missed that..

Comment: [Don't waste the otherwise guard](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85910/34531): `f n|n<0=tail.f$abs n|x<-[1..n]>>"-~"=x++"0"`.

Comment: 2 bytes to save: `...|n<0=tail$f(-n)|...`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 18 [bytes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)

```apl
'0',⍨0∘>↓'-~'⍴⍨2×|
```

`'0',⍨` character zero appended to

`0∘>` negativeness (i.e. 1 for numbers under 0; 0 for zero and up)

`↓` dropped from

`'-~'⍴⍨` the string "~-" cyclically reshaped to length

`2×` two times

`|` the absolute value

`+` plus

`0∘<` positiveness (i.e 1 for numbers over 0)

[TryAPL online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%270%27%2C%u23680%u2218%3E%u2193%27-%7E%27%u2374%u23682%D7%7C%20%u22C4%20f%A8%AF3%20%AF2%20%AF1%200%201%202%203&run)

Answer (score 5):

## [V](http://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 21 bytes

```
/ä
é
D@"ña-~ñá0kgJó--
```

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=L8OkCsOpCkRAIsOxYS1-w7HDoTBrZ0rDsy0t&input=MA)

V has *very* limited number support, and it actually has no concept of negative numbers. This means in order to support negatives (or even 0), we have to use some hacky workarounds.

Explanation:

```
/ä                  "Move forward to the first digit
é                   "And enter a newline
D                   "Delete this number, into register '"'
 @"                 "That number times:
   ñ   ñ            "Repeat the following:
    a               "  Append the string:
     -~             "  '-~'
        á0          "Append a 0
          k         "Move up a line
           gJ       "And join these two lines together
             ó--    "Remove the text '--', if it exists
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```js
x=>"-~".repeat(x<0?-x:x).slice(x<0)+0
```

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Neil

Answer (score 5):

### Ruby, 34 bytes

```
->x{("-~"*x.abs+?0)[2[0<=>x]..-1]}
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
A⁾-~ẋḊẋ¡N0
```

This is a full program. [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=QeKBvi1-4bqL4biK4bqLwqFOMA&input=&args=Mw)

#### How it works

```
A⁾-~ẋḊẋ¡N0  Main link. Argument: n

A           Take the absolute value of n.
 ⁾-~ẋ       Repeat the string "-~" that many times. Result: s
       ¡    Conditional application:
     Ḋ        Dequeue; remove the first element of s...
      ẋ N     if s, repeated -n times, is non-empty.
         0  Print the previous return value. Set the return value to 0.
            (implicit) Print the final return value.
```

Answer (score 5):

## Java 7, <s>95</s> 79 bytes

**79 bytes:**

```
String s(int x){String t=x<0?"~":"";while((x<0?++x:x--)!=0)t+="-~";return t+0;}
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
String s(int x) {
    String t = x<0 ? "~" : "";
    while((x<0 ? ++x : x--) != 0)
        t += "-~";
    return t+0;
}
```

<s>Old version (95 bytes):</s>

```
String s(int x){return new String(new char[x<0?-x:x]).replace("\0","-~").substring(x<0?1:0)+0;}
```

**Usage:**

```
class A {
    public static void main(String[]a) {
        System.out.println(s(-3));
        System.out.println(s(-2));
        System.out.println(s(-1));
        System.out.println(s(0));
        System.out.println(s(1));
        System.out.println(s(2));
        System.out.println(s(3));
    }
    static String s(int x){String t=x<0?"~":"";while((x<0?++x:x--)!=0)t+="-~";return t+0;}
}
```

[Try it here!](https://ideone.com/WjEXEd)

Output:

```
~-~-~0
~-~0
~0
0
-~0
-~-~0
-~-~-~0
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to PPCG! Nice first post!

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Hmm, that's a shorter solution than mine, so I will delete my answer and upvote yours instead. :)

Answer (score 3):

## EXCEL: <s>55</s> 33 bytes

```
=REPT("-~",IF(A1>0,A1,ABS(A1)-1))&"0"
```

Input is in the form of putting a number in the A1 cell. Formula can go anywhere except A1.

Comment: I don't think it works for negative numbers...

Answer (score 3):

### [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), <s>18</s> 14 bytes

*Took some inspiration from [Emigna's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92600/8478) to save 4 bytes.*

```
li_z"-~"*\0<>0
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cU4vezpMOwoKTGlfeiItfiIqXDA8PjAKCl1ufS8&input=LTMKLTIKLTEKMAoxCjIKMw) (As a linefeed-separated test suite.)

#### Explanation

```
li      e# Read input and convert to integer N.
_z      e# Duplicate and get |N|.
"-~"*   e# Repeat this string |N| times.
\0<     e# Use the other copy of N to check if it's negative.
>       e# If so, discard the first '-'.
0       e# Put a 0 at the end.
```

Answer (score 3):

### T-SQL, 87 bytes

```
select substring(replicate('-~',abs(x)),case when x<0then 2 else 1 end,x*x+1)+'0'from #
```

The `x*x+1` condition in substring is sufficient, since `x^2+1>=2*abs(x)` for all `x`.

As usually in SQL, the input is stored in a table:

```
create table # (x int)

insert into # values (0)
insert into # values (1)
insert into # values (-1)
insert into # values (2)
insert into # values (-2)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Vim - 31 keystrokes

First vim golf, prolly missed a ton of stuff.

```
`i-~<esc>:s/-\~-/\~-/dwp<left>ii<esc><left>d$@"<esc>a0`
```

Comment: Nice, welcome to the club! :) You could do `:s/^-` instead of `:s/-\~/\~-` and `D` instead of `d$`

Comment: Now that I think about it, I don't think this handles 0. You could get around this by incrementing before deleting with `<C-a>` and then deleting two characters off the end.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem oh, `0i` doesn't work?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. `0` moves the cursor to the first character on the current row. You can sorta use 0 as a count in V though.

Answer (score 2):

### Matlab, 61 bytes

```
x=input('');A=repmat('-~',1,abs(x));disp([A((x<0)+1:end) 48])
```

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
X,"-~"*Q0<>0+
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=X%2C%22-%7E%22%2a0%2BQ0%3C%3E&input=-2&warnings=0)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 25 bytes

```perl6
{substr '-~'x.abs~0,0>$_}
```

## Explanation:

```perl6
{
  substr
    # string repeat ｢-~｣ by the absolute value of the input
    '-~' x .abs

    # concatenate 0 to that
    ~ 0

    ,

    # ignore the first character of the string if it is negative
    0 > $_
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Jelly, <s>14</s> 12 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @Dennis (return 0 rather than concatenate "0", making this a full program only.)

```
0>‘
A⁾-~ẋṫÇ0
```

Test it at [**TryItOnline**](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=MD7igJgKQeKBvi1-4bqL4bmrw4cw&input=&args=LTU)

How?

```
0>‘      - link 1 takes an argument, the input
0>       - greater than 0? 1 if true 0 if false
  ‘      - increment

A⁾-~ẋṫÇ0 - main link takes an argument, the input
      Ç  - y = result of previous link as a monad
A        - x = absolute value of input
 ⁾-~     - the string "-~"
    ẋ    - repeat the sting x times
     ṫ   - tail repeatedString[y:] (y will be 1 or 2, Jelly lists are 1-based)
       0 - implicit print then return 0
```

Answer (score 2):

### ><>, 18 + 3 = 22 bytes

```
:?!n0$-:0):1go-
-~
```

[Try it online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=Oj8hbjAkLTowKToxZ28tCi1-&input=&args=LXYgLTQ) +3 bytes for the `​ -v` flag to initialise the stack with the input. If assuming that STDIN is empty is okay, then the following is a byte shorter:

```
:?!ni*:0):1go-
-~
```

The program keeps flipping the input `n` as necessary until it reaches 0, after which it errors out.

```
[Loop]
:?!n      If n is 0, output it as a num. If this happens then the stack is now
          empty, and the next subtraction fails
0$-       Subtract n from 0
:0)       Push (n > 0)
:1go      Output the char at (n>0, 1) which is a char from the second line
-         Subtract, overall updating n -> -n-(n>0)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PseudoD](http://github.com/alinarezrangel/PseudoD), <s>688</s> <s>579</s> 521 bytes

```
utilizar mate.pseudo
utilizar entsal.pseudo
adquirir n
adquirir a
adquirir r
adquirir i
fijar n a llamar LeerPalabra finargs
si son iguales n y CERO
escribir {0}
salir
fin
fijar a a llamar ValorAbsoluto n finargs
fijar i a CERO
si comparar Importar.Ent.Comparar n < CERO
fijar r a {~}
sino
fijar r a {-}
fin
mientras comparar Importar.Ent.Comparar i < a
escribir r finargs
si son iguales r y {~}
fijar r a {-}
Importar.Ent.Sumar i UNO i
sino
fijar r a {~}
fin
finbucle
si son iguales r y {~}
escribir {~}
fin
escribir {0}
```

Explain:

```
Read a number from STDIN;
If the number is zero (0); Then:
    Writes 0 to STDOUT and exits;
End If;
If the number is less than zero (0); Then:
    Set the fill character to "~";
Else:
    Set the fill character to "-";
End If;
For i = 0; While i is less than abs(number); do:
    Write the fill character to STDOUT;
    If the fill character is "~":
        Set the fill character to "-"
        Increment i by one
    Else:
        Set the fill character to "~"
    End if;
End for;
If the fill character is "~"; Then:
    Write "~" to STDOUT;
End If;
Write "0" to STDOUT
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Is that as small as it gets? I see some long identifiers you could probably shorten ("relleno" to "r", menos relleno :P). I think you can drop the imports for standard lib if it's only a function or code snippet too. It doesn't ask for trailing newline on output, so maybe you can change the last EscribirLinea to Escribir. Can you assign functions to shorter names(`adquirir e``fijar p a Escribir`)?

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 51 bytes

```
x=input('');[("-~"'*[1:abs(x)>0])((x<0)+1:end),'0']
```

At first blatantly copying the Matlab approach by @pajonk and then modifying some details, rewriting as an "outer product" between a vector of ones and the characters "-~" and abusing **on-the-fly-indexing** (or what it could be called) lets us save some bytes. It still pains me slightly that I can't get the index expression to take fewer bytes.

Octave allows a(i1)(i2) or even (...)(i1)(i2) for indexing where Matlab would want us to store variables in between the indexings.

```
((x<0)+1:end)
```

is far too long to describe "skip first if". There must be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 61 bytes

```php
if(0>$n=$argv[1]){echo"~";$n=~$n;}echo str_repeat("-~",$n),0;
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 58 bytes

```
<?=((0<$a=$argv[1])?'-':'').str_pad('0',2*abs($a),'~-',0);
```

Answer (score 1):

### [Labyrinth](http://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), 25 bytes

```
`?+#~.
.  ; 6
54_"#2
  @!
```

[Try it online!](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=YD8rI34uCi4gIDsgNgo1NF8iIzIKICBAIQ&input=LTM)

#### Explanation

I really like the control flow in this one. The IP runs in a figure 8 (or actually a ∞, I guess) through the code to reduce the input slowly to `0` while printing the corresponding characters.

The code starts in the upper left corner going right. The `` ` `` doesn't do anything right now. `?` reads the input and `+` adds it to the implicit zero below. Of course that doesn't do anything either, but when we run over this code again, `?` will push a zero (because we're at EOF), and `+` will then get rid of that zero.

Next the `#` pushes the stack depth, simply to ensure that there's a positive value on the stack to make the IP turn south, and `;` discards it again.

The `"` is a no-op and acts as the main branch of the code. There are three cases to distinguish:

- If the current value is positive, the IP turns right (west) and completes one round of the left loop:

  ```
  _45.`?+
  _45      Push 45.
     .     Print as character '-'.
      `    Negate the current value (thereby applying the unary minus).
       ?+  Does nothing.
  ```
- If the current value is negative, the IP turns left (east) and the following code is run:

  ```
  #26.~
  #        Push stack depth, 1.
   26      Turn it into a 126.
     .     Print as character '~'.
      ~    Bitwise NOT of the current value (applying the ~).
  ```

  Note that these two will alternate (since both change the sign of the input) until the input value is reduced to zero. At that point...
- When the current value is zero, the IP simply keeps moving south, and executes the `!` and then turns west onto the `@`. `!` prints the `0` and `@` terminates the program.

Answer (score 1):

## GolfScript

, <del>30</del> <del>24</del> 20 bytes

- Saved 6 bytes thanks to xnor.
- Saved 4 bytes thanks to Dennis.

`~."-~"\abs*\0<{(;}*0`

Input: `-5`

Output: `-5 = ~-~-~-~-~0`

#### Explanation

```
~.     # Input to integer and duplicate
"-~"   # We shall output a repetition of this string
\abs   # Move the input onto the stack and computes abs
*      # Multiply "-~" for abs(input) times
\      # Copy onto the stack the input
0<     # Is it less than 0?
{(;}*  # Yes: remove first '-' from the output
0      # Push 0
```

[Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=fi4iLX4iXGFicypcMDx7KDt9KjA&input=LTI)

Comment: You don't have to print the `2 = `, just the `-~-~0`.

Comment: You can use `{(;}*0` instead of `{(;}{}if 0`.